# How can I combine PHP and jQuery in paging controls

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement paging in PHP. First of all I am getting the number of pages as per page record and generating `<li>` links dynamically by number of pages. Like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_pages; $i++)
{
    echo '<li><a href="view_records.php?pageno='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
}
```

It's fine, but the problem is that when the number of pages is more than 10, the page number wraps to the next line. I want to scroll them by clicking left and right 10 pages each time.

Suppose I have 35 pages, so this will display all 35 pages links

```
left 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ......35 right
```

But I want only

```
left 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 right
```

When I click on `right` this will scroll right and should display

```
left 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 right
```

Again `right` will display next 10 pages link. Is there anything in JS or jQuery to control that `li` for scrolling? It will be become easy because I get total no of pages by PHP and put link of them in HTML and user can directly move to desired page.

Comment: Paging can be a complicated problem. Especially if you are trying to do anything remotely interesting. I would recommend you use an existing solution to solve this problem rather than reinvent the wheel:
https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta

Comment: there are lots of jQuery pagination plugins that will manage display for you. Easier than trying to create a php solution

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile or your own jquery codes

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for the answer. Anyway, you can initially get the first 10 page links in the page right. Then you can use jQuery to change content inside parent element of li tags (its ul). When you click on 'right', empty the content of ul element. Append new li elements using a loop to generate. You may need a hidden value to control the page limits.